# How to run nodeJS with command line argument on azure app service (windows server)?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops, iisnode

I have my bot framework service running on nodejs 14 on windows server on azure. CICD is pre configure, its pre-configured, currently service is being started by iisnode because i can see web.config and iisnode.yml file. system is running on 32bit node version. i want to run my node js with command line argument. and also setup pm2 if possible. please let me know if anyone can help

I added those commands to iisnode.yml file

```
nodeProcessCommandLine: "D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\14.16.0\node.exe"
nodeProcessCommandLine: "node --expose_gc index.js"
```

and also added below command in web.config file

```
<iisnode nodeProcessCommandLine="node --expose-gc index.js" />
```